# make: Run when any file in directory or subdirectory changes or is added

Tags: makefile

When I use this in a Makefile:

```
run: mydir/*
    do_something.sh
```

it triggers do_something.sh every time a file in mydir is added/changed. Is it possible to also trigger do_something.sh when any file in the directory-tree of mydir (i.e in any subdirectory or subdirectory of a subdirectory, etc.) changes or is added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick.

```
run: $(shell find mydir/ -type f)
    do_something.sh
```

- `run` cannot be a PHONY target, i.e. it should create a file named `run` at the end of execution of the recipe
- If any of the files in `mydir` have spaces in the name, you might get unexpected behavior

Comment: +1 for throwing a shell call in the prereqs position; I've never seen that before.